# Enviar parâmetros de uma Activity para uma classe de cálculo

Tags: java, android

Estou com uma dúvida tem um tempo, ja postei aqui uma vez mas ela não foi solucionada.
Eu gostaria de passar um parâmetro de uma Activty para uma classe de cálculo (essa classe não tem activity , é somente para calcular). Pesquisei muito a respeito e nao encontrei, pois o que eu vejo é passagem entreActivitys.

Eu fico com certa dúvida nisso porque na recuperação dos parâmetros, colocamos os intents dentro public onCreat e ao criar uma nova classe não tem isso. Como eu faria isso?

Desculpe não postar código pra ajudar nem nada, estou pelo celular.

Obrigada a atenção de todos.!

Gostaria de fazer algo do tipo. É possível? Se for, qual é a forma certa de fazer?
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI64u.png)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não serviria instanciar a classe por exemplo: ´Classe_Calculo exemplo = new Classe_Calculo(); exemplo.calcular();` isso não funciona?

Comment: posta o código da activity e da classe de calculo ; )

Comment: Oi gente. Estou pelo celular, entao não tenho como postar. Basicamente como receber as informacoes de uma activity em uma classe. Como vou recupera la com o intent se nao tem o onCreat ao voce criar uma nova classe.

Comment: Olha, só vejo 2 formas de fazer isso: Ou você registra esse objeto activity em algum lugar para que seus dados fiquem acessíveis em uma classe singleton, por exemplo, ou você criar um controller genérico e seta os dados da activity nele. Se os parâmetros alvo que você deseja mudam com frequência, é melhor guardar a referência do objeto activity mesmo.

Comment: coloquei uma foto do que eu gostaria de fazer!!

Answer (score 0):

Criando a classe:

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String nomedoarquivo;
    String servidorremoto;
    Handler handler;


    public MnhaClasse(Context context, 
                      String arquivo, 
                      String servidorremoto, 
                     Handler handler ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nomedoarquivo = arquivo;
        this.servidorremoto = servidorremoto;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
    ....
```

Na Activity você instancia a classe passando os parametros e chama o metodo execute da mesma.

```
new MinhaClasse(getActivity(), arquivo, servidorremoto,myHandler).execute(arquivo);
```